# How to combine multiple Unicode properties in perl regex?

Tags: perl, unicode

Have this script:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

use utf8;    
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

my $str = "XYZ ΦΨΩ zyz φψω";

my @greek = ($str =~ /\p{Greek}/g);
say "Greek: @greek";

my @upper = ($str =~ /\p{Upper}/g);
say "Upper: @upper";

#my @upper_greek = ($str =~ /\p{Upper+Greek}/); #wrong.
#say "Upper+Greek: @upper_greek";
```

Is possible combine multiple unicode properties? E.g how to select only `Upper and Greek`, and get the wanted:

```
Greek: Φ Ψ Ω φ ψ ω
Upper: X Y Z Φ Ψ Ω
Upper+Greek: Φ Ψ Ω      #<-- how to get this?
```

Comment: @HåkonHægland That will still return `X Y Z` as well

Comment: I have the same question but for JavaScript regex !!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We want to perform an AND operation, so we can't use

```
/(?:\p{Greek}|\p{Upper})/         # Greek OR Upper
```

or

```
/[\p{Greek}\p{Upper}]/            # Greek OR Upper
```

Since 5.18, one can use regex sets.

```
/(?[ \p{Greek} & \p{Upper} ])/    # Greek AND Upper
```

This requires `use experimental qw( regex_sets );` before 5.36. But it's safe to add this and use the feature as far back as its introduction as an experimental feature in 5.18, since no change was made to the feature since then.

---

There are some other approaches that can be used in older versions of Perl, but they are indisputably harder to read.

One way of achieving AND in a regex is using lookarounds.

```
/\p{Greek}(?<=\p{Upper})/         # Greek AND Upper
```

Another way of getting an AND is to negate an OR. [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) tells us

```
NOT( Greek AND Upper )  ⇔  NOT(Greek) OR NOT(Upper)
```

so

```
Greek AND Upper  ⇔  NOT( NOT(Greek) OR NOT(Upper) )
```

This gives us

```
/[^\P{Greek}\P{Upper}]/           # Greek AND Upper
```

This is more efficient then using a lookbehind.

Comment: @jm666 `NOT (NOT GREEK) OR (NOT UPPER) = GREEK AND UPPER`

Comment: Is there a reason why there is no out-of-the-box way to `AND` within a regex? (Similar to `|` for `OR`)

Comment: @Zaid, Aside from AND-THEN (as in "AB" = "A AND-THEN B"), what would you AND? If you want to AND character properties, then that's why `(?[ ])` was created. The other major need for AND is addressed by `/A/ && /B/`.

Answer (score 7):

This works in 5.14.0 as well:

```
sub InUpperGreek {
    return <<'END'
+utf8::Greek
&utf8::Upper
END
}

my @upper_greek = ($str =~ /\p{InUpperGreek}/g);
say "Upper Greek: @upper_greek";
```

Not sure if that's simpler. :)  For more information on how this works, see the [perlunicode](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlunicode#User-Defined-Character-Properties) documentation on user-defined character properties.